# Efficiently split a string using multiple separators and retaining each separator?

Tags: python, string

I need to split strings of data using each character from `string.punctuation` and `string.whitespace` as a separator.

Furthermore, I need for the separators to remain in the output list, in between the items they separated in the string.

For example,

```
"Now is the winter of our discontent"
```

should output:

```
['Now', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'winter', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'our', ' ', 'discontent']
```

I'm not sure how to do this without resorting to an orgy of nested loops, which is unacceptably slow. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm guessing since you accepted DSM's answer you intended for consecutive punctuation characters to stay grouped together?

Comment: @johnthexiii, I accepted it because it didn't use `re`.  The option to group consecutive separators is an added bonus, although I'm sure it can be done easily with regex as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A different non-regex approach from the others:

```
>>> import string
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> special = set(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
>>> s = "One two  three    tab\ttabandspace\t end"
>>> 
>>> split_combined = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, lambda c: c in special)]
>>> split_combined
['One', ' ', 'two', '  ', 'three', '    ', 'tab', '\t', 'tabandspace', '\t ', 'end']
>>> split_separated = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, lambda c: c if c in special else False)]
>>> split_separated
['One', ' ', 'two', '  ', 'three', '    ', 'tab', '\t', 'tabandspace', '\t', ' ', 'end']
```

Could use `dict.fromkeys` and `.get` instead of the `lambda`, I guess.

[edit]

Some explanation:

`groupby` accepts two arguments, an iterable and an (optional) keyfunction.  It loops through the iterable and groups them with the value of the keyfunction:

```
>>> groupby("sentence", lambda c: c in 'nt')
<itertools.groupby object at 0x9805af4>
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby("sentence", lambda c: c in 'nt')]
[(False, ['s', 'e']), (True, ['n', 't']), (False, ['e']), (True, ['n']), (False, ['c', 'e'])]
```

where terms with contiguous values of the keyfunction are grouped together.  (This is a common source of bugs, actually -- people forget that they have to sort by the keyfunc first if they want to group terms which might not be sequential.)

As @JonClements guessed, what I had in mind was

```
>>> special = dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation + string.whitespace, True)
>>> s = "One two  three    tab\ttabandspace\t end"
>>> [''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(s, special.get)]
['One', ' ', 'two', '  ', 'three', '    ', 'tab', '\t', 'tabandspace', '\t ', 'end']
```

for the case where we were combining the separators.  `.get` returns `None` if the value isn't in the dict.

Comment: Or another option instead of lambda (albeit it ugly) `groupby(s, special.__contains__)` ...

Comment: @JonClements: yeah, I think I'd use a dict before I'd use a special method. :^)

Comment: `partial(contains, special)` then ? ;)

Comment: @DSM, What would be the advantage of using a dict instead of the lambda?

Comment: @blz: really, only the appearance.  [There's a bit of a performance hit relative to a builtin, but speed isn't a problem here.]

Comment: @DSM, Ok, cool!  Could you suggest a way to group all consecutive separators into a string, even if they're different?  (e.g.:  '\t\n ').  Thanks so much -- This answer really looks great!

Comment: @blz: sure.  As for the consecutive separators -- that's what split_combined is (look after `'tabandspace'`).

Comment: @DSM,  I read too quickly, it seems!  Thank you so much, accepting now!

Comment: `special = dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation + string.whitespace, True); split_combined = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s, special.get)]` is what I think DSM means... @blz [wrt .fromkeys anyway]

Answer (score 7):

```
import re
import string

p = re.compile("[^{0}]+|[{0}]+".format(re.escape(
    string.punctuation + string.whitespace)))

print p.findall("Now is the winter of our discontent")
```

I'm no big fan of using regexps for all problems, but I don't think you have much choice in this if you want it fast and short.

I'll explain the regexp since you're not familiar with it:

- `[...]` means any of the characters inside the square brackets
- `[^...]` means any of the characters *not* inside the square brackets
- `+` behind means *one or more of the previous thing*
- `x|y` means to match either `x` or `y`

So the regexp matches 1 or more characters where either *all* must be punctuation and whitespace, or *none* must be. The `findall` method finds all non-overlapping matches of the pattern.

Comment: You probably want to use `re.escape(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)`, otherwise I think your character classes will end early on `]`.

Comment: I don't think it works for "..Now is the winter of our discontent"

Comment: @F.J Fixed. And `"..Now is the winter of our discontent"` works for me.

Comment: @lazyr shouldn't '..' be '.', '.'

Comment: @lazyr,  I'm accepting DSM's answer using itertools because I'm already using itertools in my current project and this would avoid adding an additional import.  I just wanted to thank you for your answer -- I look forward to learning regex soon!

Comment: @blz As I said, I'm no big fan of regexp solutions. DSM's answer was impressive, and I suspect it's the best you could hope for in terms of speed, outside of regexps (this solution is 4.5 times faster than his, if you don't count the compiling of the regexp. Including compile, it's about equally fast.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```python
import re
re.split('(['+re.escape(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)+']+)',"Now is the winter of our discontent")
```

Explanation from [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

Comment: Ugly behavior with consecutive spaces: `re.split(r'( )', ' '*2)` results in `['', ' ', '', ' ', '']`.

Comment: @F.J consecutive spaces/separators should be handled better now.

Answer (score 3):

Solution in linear (`O(n)`) time:

Let's say you have a string:

```
original = "a, b...c    d"
```

First convert all separators to space:

```
splitters = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
trans = string.maketrans(splitters, ' ' * len(splitters))
s = original.translate(trans)
```

Now `s == 'a  b   c    d'`. Now you can use `itertools.groupby` to alternate between spaces and non-spaces:

```
result = []
position = 0
for _, letters in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: c == ' '):
    letter_count = len(list(letters))
    result.append(original[position:position + letter_count])
    position += letter_count
```

Now `result == ['a', ', ', 'b', '...', 'c', '    ', 'd']`, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the text you are dealing with, you may be able to simplify your concept of delimiters to "anything other than letters and numbers".  If this will work, you can use the following regex solution:

```
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\d]+|[^a-zA-Z\d]', text)
```

This assumes that you want to split on each individual delimiter character even if they occur consecutively, so `'foo..bar'` would become `['foo', '.', '.', 'bar']`.  If instead you expect `['foo', '..', 'bar']`, use `[a-zA-Z\d]+|[^a-zA-Z\d]+` (only difference is adding `+` at the very end).

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
from string import whitespace, punctuation
import re

pattern = re.escape(whitespace + punctuation)
print re.split('([' + pattern + '])', 'now is the winter of')
```

Comment: Ugly behavior with consecutive delimiters: `re.split('([' + pattern + '])', '..')` results in `['', '.', '', '.', '']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace

s = "..test. and stuff"

f = lambda s, c: s + ' ' + c + ' ' if c in punctuation else s + c
l =  sum([reduce(f, word).split() for word in s.split()], [])

print l
```

Answer (score 0):

For any arbitrary collection of separators:

```
def separate(myStr, seps):
    answer = []
    temp = []
    for char in myStr:
        if char in seps:
            answer.append(''.join(temp))
            answer.append(char)
            temp = []
        else:
            temp.append(char)
    answer.append(''.join(temp))
    return answer

In [4]: print separate("Now is the winter of our discontent", set(' '))
['Now', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'winter', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'our', ' ', 'discontent']

In [5]: print separate("Now, really - it is the winter of our discontent", set(' ,-'))
['Now', ',', '', ' ', 'really', ' ', '', '-', '', ' ', 'it', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'winter', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'our', ' ', 'discontent']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This might start to be slow when you use `string.punctuation + string.whitespace` as `seps` argument -- for each character, you're searching through a list of separators in linear time.

Comment: Not if you pass them in as a `set`

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import chain, cycle, izip

s = "Now is the winter of our discontent"
words = s.split()

wordsWithWhitespace = list( chain.from_iterable( izip( words, cycle([" "]) ) ) )
# result : ['Now', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'winter', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'our', ' ', 'discontent', ' ']
```