# How to split a string by multiple characters and keep the split chars in return value?

Tags: python

This is a sample input:

```
(a1 b2 c3)
```

Split by ' ', '(', ')', this is the desired output:

```
['(', 'a1', ' ', 'b2', ' ', 'c3', ')']
```

What is the Pythonism way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: Efficiently split a string using multiple separators and retaining each separator? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186067/efficiently-split-a-string-using-multiple-separators-and-retaining-each-separator)

Comment: thank you DSM, this question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @orokusaki: you'll note I didn't vote to close.  That said, the same set of solutions applies to each problem, both regex and non-regex.

Comment: The another question seems to be way more difficult than mine :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python's [regular expression module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(\w+)', '(a1 b2 c3)')
['(', 'a1', ' ', 'b2', ' ', 'c3', ')']
```

or, with `findall` as in orokusaki's answer, but with character classes (which also count `_` as a word character):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\W+|\w+', '(a1 b2 c3)')
['(', 'a1', ' ', 'b2', ' ', 'c3', ')']
```

Or, if you want to be explicit about only splitting on `(`, , `)`:

```
>>> re.split(r'([^\(\) ]+)', '(a1 b2 c3)')
['(', 'a1', ' ', 'b2', ' ', 'c3', ')']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '(a1 a2 a3)')
['(', 'a1', ' ', 'a2', ' ', 'a3', ')']
```